# How do I create 9 images on the same page that switch every 5 seconds between 3 images. I can do one but can not do multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, timer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currPic = 1;
var totPics = 3;
var keepTime;

function setupPicChange() {
    keepTime = setTimeout("changePic()", 5000);
}

function changePic() {
    currPic++;
    if (currPic > totPics) currPic = 1;
    document.getElementById("picture1").src = "advert" + currPic + ".jpg";
    setupPicChange();
}
</script>
```

Hello this is my script to have an image that changes three times after 5 seconds, it works perfectly, but can somebody in very simple terms show me how to make this apply to 9 different images, all changing 3 times, at the same time, but to different images?

eg advert 1, will change to advert 2, and then to advert 3................
   below it................. advert 4 will change to advert 5 and then to advert 6................  below that ........................ advert 7 will change to advert 8 and then to advert 9......... all the way up to advert 27.   They wont actually be adverts, thats just a good example of what I need to know.

Thanks once again guys!!!!

Comment: Why the jQuery tag, I see none.

Comment: do they all have the id picture1?

Comment: Try to solve this yourself, then come back when you have problems.

Answer (score 3):

You should think about abstracting the logic you're currently using to apply to a set of images in general. Here's an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rotators = [
    { id: 'picture1', images: ['pic1.jpg', 'pic2.jpg', 'pic3.jpg'], selectedIndex: 0 },
    { id: 'picture2', images: ['pic4.jpg', 'pic5.jpg', 'pic6.jpg'], selectedIndex: 0 },
    { id: 'picture3', images: ['pic7.jpg', 'pic8.jpg', 'pic9.jpg'], selectedIndex: 0 }
];

var updateImages = function() {
    for (var i=0; i < rotators.length; i++) {
        var rotator = rotators[i];
        rotator.selectedIndex++;
        if (rotator.selectedIndex >= rotator.images.length) {
            rotator.selectedIndex = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById(rotator.id).src = rotator.images[rotator.selectedIndex];
    }
};
var timer = setInterval(updateImages, 5000);
</script>
```

This makes the components you're currently operating on (the id of the image you want to change, the images you want to rotate through, and your current position in those images) properties of objects that are placed in an array. Then the function that does the updating (like your changePic method) can loop over all of those objects in the array and use the same logic to update each of them.

I also changed the setTimeout call to setInterval, which will call the provided function every X ms, instead of calling it just once and then having to reset the timer.